# Objective-C - Unknwn Type Name

Tags: objective-c

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Dropbox_Manager.h"

@interface FileSystemManager : NSObject {
    NSFileManager           *fileManager;

    BOOL fileExisting;
    BOOL contentIsEqual;
    BOOL isWriteable;

    Dropbox_Manager    *dropBox_Manager; // Here Xcode shows the Error !!!!!
}
```

I don't get any other error in the project, but Xcode can't find the Type.

Comment: What's inside `Dropbox_Manager.h` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
#import "Dropbox_Manager.h"
```

with

```
@class Dropbox_Manager;
```

Then add

```
#import "Dropbox_Manager.h"
```

to your FileSystemManager.m file

Comment: That's not a solution since Xcode won't be able to find a class in the `FileSystemManager.m` file. You're just moving place of error from header to implementation file. Yes, it is a right way to do the file import in cocoa, but it's not a solution in current situation.

Comment: I have had problems with Xcode not properly recognizing the class when importing the header file. However, you're right if the problem is in the Dropbox_Manager.h file.